# Facebook One Click access using Titanium Studio

Tags: iphone, facebook, authentication, titanium-mobile, oneclick

I came across Facebook's new way of integration with IPhone apps. Instead of displaying web view to login with Facebook through an app, they have changed it so that the user can login with the Facebook app in their device.

[Facebook One click access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/#step1)

I would like to know if this is possible with Titanium Studio. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I am right you want to integrate facebook in your app. The first step is getting the app ID you can get it here [graph-api docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/graphapi/)

And refer to the [refer official docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Facebook/)
follow the necessary steps and you will get what you need. 
Hope it helps.